# Any app that allows you to send SMS from your phone (Android) with an API?

Tags: gratis, android, api, sms

I'm trying to find something like Google's Android messages, which has a [web interface](https://messages.google.com). I don't necessarily care about the web interface though. I'm much more interested in how Android messages manages to send and receive text messages from a computer. I'm looking for an app that exposes API to do that, so that I could hook it up to pidgin. The problem is that the ones I found (Pulse SMS, Pushbullet) are paid/have limited free functionality. I am ok with self-hosting; is there anything like what I'm trying to find?

Comment: I used sms control center https://smscontrolcenter.en.softonic.com/ for a while to manage sms from pc, it worked but I did not search hard enough to find its api for command line. A short github search https://github.com/search?q=sms+windows led to android messages desktop: https://github.com/chrisknepper/android-messages-desktop. Haven't tested the latter though.